# Remove lines with only NAs from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to remove the lines from a data.table that only contain NAs.

```
> tab = data.table(A = c(1, NA, 3), B = c(NA, NA, 3))
> tab
    A  B
1:  1 NA
2: NA NA
3:  3  3
```

Normally I would do it with `apply(dat, 1, ...)` which unfortunately does not work on a data.table but it leads me to this inelegant solution:

```
> tab[apply(as.data.frame(tab), 1, function(x) !all(is.na(x))), ]
   A  B
1: 1 NA
2: 3  3
```

How can this be achieved the fastest way without knowing the column names?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work on a data.table?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `is.na` and `&`

```
tab[!Reduce(`&`, lapply(tab, is.na))]
#   A  B
#1: 1 NA
#2: 3  3
```

---

Or a compact but not so efficient approach would be

```
tab[rowSums(!is.na(tab)) != 0L]
```

Also, as commented by @Frank, a join based approach,

```
tab[!tab[NA_integer_], on = names(tab)]
```

Comment: Probably super inefficient, but there's also `df[!df[NA_integer_], on=names(df)]` -- anti-join on all columns against a row of NAs.

Comment: Ist there a way to make this code exclude the first column? I have a data.table where I want to remove rows which are completely empty apart from the first column.

Comment: @Tom Can you please post as a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871943/remove-rows-which-have-all-nas-apart-from-the-first-column

Answer (score 2):

Another idea:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) < length(.))
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite like

```
tab <- tab[sapply(1:nrow(tab), function(i){!all(is.na(tab[i,]))}),]
```

It is intuitive to me, but I'm not sure it is the fastest approach.

HTH