# Remove rows which have all NA's, apart from the first column

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have a data.table which was formed by taking the differences between two panel observations using:

```
tab <- tab[,
   lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x)), 
   by = A, 
   .SDcols = (sapply(tab, is.numeric))
  ]

tab = data.table(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2), B = c(NA, 2, NA, 1), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 2), D=c(NA, 3, NA, 2))
tab
    A  B  C  D
1:  1  NA NA NA
2:  1  2  NA 3
3:  2  NA NA NA
4:  2  1  2  2
```

I would like to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525383/remove-lines-with-only-nas-from-data-table):

```
tab <- tab [!Reduce(`&`, lapply(tab , is.na))]
```

to remove rows 1 and 3, but this does not work because the first column is not NA. How can I adapt the code to solve this?

Desired outcome:

```
    A  B  C  D
1:  1  2  NA 3
2:  2  1  2  2
```

Comment: so drop rows that (when ignoring column A) have only NA?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Cath Because there is no data.table answer in the target.  I don't have to check into whether the dupe target itself is nested to another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we can specify the columns in `.SDcols`

```
tab[tab [, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD , is.na)), .SDcols = 2:ncol(tab)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tab[tab[, rowSums(!is.na(.SD)) > 1, .SDcols = -1]]
```